# Any reason why Ubuntu's man page on crontab(5) is less informative?

Tags: cron, manpage, info

Why is the `man` page for `crontab(5)` at [manpages.ubuntu.com](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/en/man5/crontab.5.html) less informative than corresponding `man` page at [linux.die.net](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab)?

Compare

> The "sixth" field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be run. The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or % character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified in the SHELL variable of the cronfile. Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (), will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first % will be sent to the command as standard input.

from the linux.die.net link and

> The  ``sixth'' field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be
>          run.  The entire command portion  of  the  line  will  be  executed  by
>          /bin/sh  or  by  the  shell  specified  in  the  SHELL  variable of the
>          cronfile.

from the manpages.ubuntu.com link.

I should mention that the `info` page about `crontab(5)` on my 13.10 does include this information.

```
info crontab\(5\)
```

show me this:

[image: info crontab]

And notice that `Info: (*manpages*)crontab(5)` is present in the bar at the bottom.

Comment: May be because http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/crontab.5.html is provided by a different package (`bcron_0.09-13_i386`) than the one in http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab and the author(s) didn't think those details were important. Just a guess.